# 89 D100, repair, fan ate radiator

Tags: dodge, radiator, fan, water-pump

Okay rod in waterpump separated from baffles leaned forward and the fan ate the radiator. FFW. Got all the replacement parts and pulled it apart to replace the jacked up parts ie: Waterpump, radiator, fan, fan clutch etc.

Now the problem: I had to unbolt the steel plate in front of the Waterpump that also connects to the  timing belt, sump pump/smog pump wtev.. , and all the pulleys. There was a small steel piece (similar to angle iron) looks as though it's a mount to keep the plate stabilized and I'm having trouble locating where it went to reinstall it. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you did not take pictures, then do a search for a workshop manual or even a youtube video..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Posting pics would go a long way.

Comment: If you go to the dealership parts department, they have exploded drawings of the various assemblies. Bring the part with you and you will see where it goes.